# Finding the generating function of 1/(n+1)!

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I seem to be stuck on this question. Or rather, not sure if I solved it correctly.

So I know that

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{(n+1)}*\frac{1}{(n)!}$$

Therefore, I can change $\frac{1}{(n+1)}$ to $1-n+n^2-n^3....$

which would make:

$$f(n)=\frac{(1-n+n^2-n^3...)}{(n)!}$$

Would that be the final answer or is there another way to write $\frac{1}{(n)!}$ to answer this question correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is $$\frac{e^x-1}{x}$$

Comment: Please take a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to learn how to use proper formatting.

Comment: What is (e^x - 1)/x? the overall answer or just 1/(n)!?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner ^^

Comment: Anybody want to help explain? Just giving me the answer does nothing. Besides, I'm not even sure if that is the answer or what. "It is X" doesn't say anything. Still need help!

Comment: It seems that you are misunderstanding the concept of a generating function generated by a sequence. Check, for example, this link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneratingFunction.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to model $\frac{1}{n+1}$ as a geometric series, then,
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots
$$
so letting $x = -n$ you indeed have
$$
\frac{1}{1+n} = 1 - n + n^2 - n^3 \pm \ldots
$$
but I don't see how this can help you.

---

You are looking for a generating function for the sequence $a_n = \frac1{(n+1)!}$, so you get
$$
\begin{split}
f(x)
 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k 
  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k+1)!} \\
 &= \frac{1}{x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} \quad \text{use } m = k+1\\
 &= \frac{1}{x} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m!} \\
 &= \frac{1}{x} \left[\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m!}\right) -1\right]
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish this by recognizing the sum as a Taylor series for a well-known function?

Comment: an exponential?

Comment: i dont understand where 1/x came from

Comment: @DevAllanPer you take $1/x$ outside and change the exponent from $x^k$ to $x^{k+1}$ inside to match the exponent to the factorial on the bottom.

Comment: oh. Finally, where did that "-1" come from on your very last step?

Comment: @DevAllanPer index change in the sum -- the one before was starting from 1, the one after from 0, so i added the index-0 term, and needed to subtract it...