# Generating Function of 3(5^n)-2n

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am unsure as to whether or not I solved this generating function correctly.
$a_n = 3(5^n) − 2n$ and the generating function is given by
$$
\begin{split}
&=3\sum 5^n - 2 \sum n\\
&=3(1+5+5^2+5^3...) -2(1+2+3+4…)\\
&= 3 \times \frac{5}{1-n} -2 \times \frac{n}{(1-n)^2}\\
&= \frac{15}{1-n} - \frac{2n}{(1-n)^2}
\end{split}
$$
Does that look correct?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Your title has $5^n$ but the text has $5n$.  Please correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. Let $a_n = 3 \cdot 5^n - 2n$ and then
$$
\begin{split}
A(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k \\
     &= 3 \sum_{k=0}^\infty 5^k x^k - 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty k x^k\\
     &= 3 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (5x)^k - 2x \sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^{k-1}\\
     &= \frac{3}{1-5x} - 2x \frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac{1}{1-x}\right]
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish this?

Comment: whyd you change 2 to 2x (from step one to two)?

Comment: @DevAllanPer because I want to fit $\sum kx^k$ to $\sum kx^{k-1}$ as the latter sum is just a derivative of the geometric series

Comment: Oh okay. Why does 5 get raised to the k?

Comment: Wait thats just part of the question, nvm

Comment: Hate to ask for more help but could you help me with this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978134/finding-the-generating-function-of-1-n1 ?

Comment: @DevAllanPer posted an answer there as well

Comment: Is it just me, or is that page unaccessible?

Comment: i cant see it anymore :(